# .NET efcore 7 JSON COLUMN PROBLEMS

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

as you know, jsoncolumn support has arrived for efcore7.

I quickly used

yes, I had no problems with creating columns with migration. I added new data

but i have the following problem in query operation

[image]

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{


  builder.Entity<IdentitySchema>().OwnsMany(
       identitySchema => identitySchema.AuthorityCodes, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
       {
         var q=ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
       })
      .OwnsMany(
       identitySchema => identitySchema.UserIds, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
       {
         var x= ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
       }); ;


  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}


  public class UserAg
  {
    public string UserId { get; set; }
  }

 _context.IdentitySchema.Select(f => new
        {
          f.UserIds,
          f.AuthorityCodes
        }).Where(f => f.UserIds.Any(f => f.UserId == "1")).ToList();
```

Comment: Post the exception as text, not images. You can easily get the full exception text by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup, or calling `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: On the other hand, what you try to do, even if it works, will have to scan the entire table to parse the JSON fields and extract the data. If you have 100K rows, you'll have to scan all of them every time you run this query. JSON support doesn't mean you can treat JSON fields as tables or value lists. You can only do what can be translated to SQL with JSON functions. Those operations won't benefit from any indexes so they'll have to process all rows.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28616 Thank you for your answer, I leave the link so that it can be noted on similar issues. they are aware of the problem. Currently no support for this complex query

Comment: Which is A Good Thing. This `UserIds` property is simply bad design. This should be a table, not an unindexed JSON string. You gain no flexibility but end up paying a huge performance penalty. No matter what EF Core does it can't make the database act as if that column is an indexed table

Comment: just making a field to hold user ids. .NET 7
In the presentation, it was stated that it works faster than defragmentation and indexing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0W2vcYMoJ8g
do you not agree?

Comment: There's no "just" in this. It's a fundamental database design bug. `it was stated that it works faster than defragmentation and indexing.` you misunderstood what was said. .NET 7 doesn't affect how the database works and executes SQL queries.